# Visual C++ Forms: Capture global keydown without blocking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have created a standard windows forms application in Visual Studio 2010.

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
   ...
}
```

I want to capture keydown events globally (if I am in an other application, my form shall react to keydowns too).
I am using **RegisterHotKey** and **WndProc** to listen to keydowns. But this blocks the regeisterd keys for other applications:

```
RegisterHotKeyA((HWND) this->Handle.ToPointer(), iHotkID_Marker, 0, VK_ADD );
```

Is there a way to pass the keys to the system or to capture keydowns without blocking?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're using RegisterHotKey, but you probably want to look at creating a [Windows Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx) procedure to obtain global keyboard events.